# Wordpress: How to include a custom field in an array (SmplePie)

Tags: wordpress, rss, simplepie

Wordpress 2.8.4, Simple Pie Plugin 2.2.1

I'm having this:

```
<?php echo SimplePieWP(
array(
   'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=fifa10%20trailer&client=ytapi-youtube-search&alt=rss&v=2'
),
array(
   'items' => '1')
); ?>
```

Instead of `fifa10` I'd like to have the value of a custom field with the key `name-of-game` in there.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You get the value of a Wordpress custom field with [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name-of-game', true)
```

To include it in your function call to SimplePieWP, use string concatenation with `.` (dot):

```
<?php echo SimplePieWP(array('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q=' .
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name-of-game', true) .
'%20trailer&client=ytapi-youtube-search&alt=rss&v=2'),array('items' => '1')); ?>
```